# installing a cmake target in two different folders

Tags: cmake

My source tree includes several executables and shared libraries (dlls). I would like to change my cmakelists.txt files so that executables are installed in multiple destination folders on the installer's sytem.

Source Tree

```
  Editor
    Editor.cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
  Game
    Game.cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
  SharedLib
    SharedLib.cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
```

Desired install directory structure

```
Editor/
  MyEditor.exe
  MySharedLib.dll

Game/
  MyGame.exe
  MySharedLib.dll
```

Currently I use a install(TARGET MySharedLib RUNTIME DESTINATION Editor) but I also need to install MySharedLib for a second time and into Game directory.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: A very similar example is given in the [official CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/install.html#installing-targets).

Comment: Thank you. I don't however see how this would work. Because install() fails when the target is not in the same directory. I tried to put the line install(TARGETS MySharedLib RUNTIME DESTINATION Game) in Game/CMakeLists.txt and that fails with the error: install TARGETS given target "MySharedLib " which does not exist in this
  directory.

Comment: You need to put `install(TARGETS)` commands into the CMakeLists.tx file which defines the target(s). But you can install each target to an arbitrary number of destinations, by using multiple `install()` commands.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to specify multiple install locations for a cmake target by calling install() multiple times (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/install.html#installing-targets).

However this call can only take place in the cmakelists.txt file of the targets directory.